# Hyperlinking URL value in JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How can I set the URL value in my JSON file to a hyperlink when displayed in the table?

JSON

```
{
  "one": "http://urltovideo.mp4",
  "two": "The second list item",
  "three": "The third list item"
}
```

jQuery

```
$.getJSON( "test.json", function( data ) {
  var items = [];
  $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
    items.push( "<div class='panel panel-default'><div class='panel-heading'>" + key + "</div><div     
    class='panel-body'><a href=''>" + val + "</a></li></div></div>" );
  });

  $( "<ol/>", {
    "class": "my-new-list",
    html: items.join( "" )
  }).fadeIn(900).appendTo( "body" );
});
```

Comment: you just need to go a little bit more slowly on the items.push line. Maybe you want an if statement before that, to separate out hyperlinks?

Comment: [Aren't those hyperlinks already?](http://jsfiddle.net/1L7hf6L5/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if `val` is containing a link:

```
$.each( data, function( key, val ) {
    var link = (val.indexOf('http') > -1) ? '<a href="' + val + '">' + val + '</a>' : val;

    items.push( '<div class="panel panel-default"><div class="panel-heading">' + key + '</div><div     
    class="panel-body">' + link + '</li></div></div>');
  });
```

Also, for cleaner code, you should use `"` for HTML attributes like `class="..."` and `'` for Javascript strings, like: `'<a href="' + val + '">'`

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danielgasser/b3eckzmw/)

Comment: I can see how that should work, but its returning undefined as the displayed value, and the URL value.